# Can't access any submodules in Python unless directly imported

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

Here's an example:

```
import scipy
scipy.signal
```

This gives the error: `module 'scipy' has no attribute 'signal'`

However, this works:

```
from scipy import signal
```

This also works:

```
import scipy.signal
```

And then once that is run, `scipy.signal` then works.

I'm getting this error in Anaconda (Spyder) as well as when running `python3` and trying to access submodules in the terminal.  I tried with multiple packages.

I'm using an M1 Mac purchased only a few months ago.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error. This is how the scipy API is designed. You can read about the scipy api [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/)

Comment: Maybe it's a coincidence but I tried multiple libraries where I'm fairly sure I've always done it like this (i.e., importing the entire package - I've definitely always done it like that with scipy).  Then I tried with numpy and did not get the error.

Comment: Some libraries have parent packages import subpackages, but the practice comes with caveats -- mostly, makes that one big import slower because it's pulling in things not everyone will need.